# Как загрузить страницу с нужным http-заголовком Authorization

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-security

Разрабатываю авторизацию на сайте с помощью JWT-токенов: передача access токена и его валидация выполняются без ошибок:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authz -> authz
                                .requestMatchers("/person/hello/user").authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                                .and()
                                .addFilterAfter(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                ).build();
    }
```

```
     function sendHello() {
       let res_token = $('.res').text()
       let header = document.querySelector('.header')
       header.innerHTML = res_token
       fetch('https://localhost:8081/person/hello/user', {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: new Headers({
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res_token,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           })
       });
```

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @GetMapping("hello/user")
    public String helloUser(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Личный кабинет");
        return "private";
    }
```

Ответ сервера, в котором я получаю HTML-код:

```
URL Запроса:
https://localhost:8081/person/hello/user
Метод Запроса:
GET
Код Статуса:
200
Удаленный Адрес:
[::1]:8081
Правило Для URL Перехода:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Authorization:
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9...
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json
```

Но проблема в том. что мне необходимо загрузить страницу Личного Кабинета с нужным заголовком Authorization, а не получить HTML-код в ответ.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно предпринять

Comment: Можно через `HttpServletRequest request` узнать заголовоки и их содержимое. Очень странно увидеть в запросе `person/hello/user` с заголовком `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` хтмл страницу... Из вопроса я не понимаю что требуется получить?

Comment: При тестах в Postman сервер выдает ответ в виде html-кода. А необходимо после отправки запроса через fetch загружать страницу Личного кабинета с access-токеном в заголовке авторизации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понимаю то вам нужно вернуть вместо как вы назвали HTML кода ( что по сути является деталями HTTP ответа  )  полноценную страницу личного кабинета пользователя с установленными заголовками `Authorization` . В проекте я вижу вы используйте шаблон MVC. Вы можете выполнить вашу задачу несколькими способами :

1. **Используя** `HttpServletResponse`

```
@GetMapping("hello/user")
public String helloUser(Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
   model.addAttribute("title", "Личный кабинет");
   response.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9...");
   return "private";
}
```

Код выше является простым примером как можно установить заголовки для страницы. Вы также можете получить токен из запроса и вставить его в возвращаемую страницу.

```
@GetMapping("hello/user")
public String helloUser(Model model, HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) {
   model.addAttribute("title", "Личный кабинет");

   // Забираем токен из запроса 
   String tokenInRequest = request.getHeader("Authorization");
   response.setHeader("Authorization", tokenInRequest); // Устанавливаем заголовок 
   response.setContentType("text/html"); // Устанавливаем тип возвращаемого контента 
   response.setStatus(200); // Устанавливаем код ответа 
   return "private";
}
```

Данный код забирает токен из запроса и вставляет его в возвращаемую страницу

2. **Используя** `ResponseEntity<>`

```
@GetMapping("hello/user")
public ResponseEntity<String> helloUser(Model model , HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "Личный кабинет");
    String tokenInRequest = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", tokenInRequest);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>("private", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Данный код выполняет туже самую задачу что и в первом варианте однако использует другой тип возвращаемого значения. Вы также можете использовать аннотацию `@RequestHeader()` она по моему мнению лучше подходит для этих целей. Также стоит обратить внимание на JavaScript код , в вашем случае код выполняющийся в браузере, может отправлять HTTP-запросы на сервер и получать ответы от него, но он не способен напрямую отображать HTML-страницы. Попробуйте его модифицировать следующим образом

```js
function sendHello() {
    let res_token = $('.res').text()
    let header = document.querySelector('.header')

    fetch('https://localhost:8081/person/hello/user', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.text()) // Преобразуем ответ в текст
    .then(data => {
        // Вставляем полученный текст на страницу
        header.innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Произошла ошибка:', error);
    });
}
```

Данный код преобразует ответ в текст и вставляет его на страницу.
Надеюсь смог вам помочь.

Comment: так и не загружается страница Личного кабинета. При всех трех вариантах и несмотря на ответ "200"

Comment: @andreydragunov Я модифицировал свой ответ , попробуйте изменить `JavaScript`  код на тот который я предоставил в измененном ответе. Проблема может быть локализована на клиенте , так как с точки зрения сервера код который я предоставил должен работать.